# Bootstrap column exact width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the bootstrap grid system and I've put a custom checkbox in column 1. There's a gap though as the checkbox is only 48px wide. Is there any way to make the first column 48px wide and make the second column variable so it pushes up against the checkbox? Here's an image to explain!

[image]

Here's my code...

```html
<div class="row ">
    <div class="form-group col-md-1 col-sm-12 col">
        <div class="check has-js" style="width:56px;font-size:14px;;text-align:left;padding-right:none">
        <label class="label_check testCheck" for="radioTheme1"><input id="radioTheme1" name="radioTheme" type="radio"/></label>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-12 col"><input class="testInput" type="text" placeholder="Name"/></div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-5 col-sm-12 col"><input class="testInput" type="text" placeholder="URL"/></div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-12 col">
        <select class="testInput">
          <option value="Single Page">Single Page</option>
          <option value="Multi Page">Multi Page</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks guys :)

Comment: on the mobile view, you want the check box to be alone on the line ?

Comment: Yes, I'm going to make a label appear next to it with media queries